# Memory limit exceeded error when reading a large file with node js and readline

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, readline

I am getting a memory error when using readline.  The section of code is shown below:

```
            var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
                input: require('fs').createReadStream('/tmp/temp.ttl')
            });
            let entity;
            let tripleKey;
            let triple;
            console.log('file ready for processing');
            lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
                triple = parser.parse(line)[0];
                if (triple) {
                    tripleKey = datastore.key('triple');
                    entity = prepare_entity(tripleKey, triple);
                    lineReader.pause();
                    datastore.save(entity).then(()=>lineReader.resume());                      
                    number_of_rows += 1;
            };
```

I thought all memory for the 'on' line event is pre-allocated as it is outside the loop.  So my question is, what could be causing the consumption of memory in this section code?

In response to Doug, changing the readline to be fully streaming now shows the memory limit error after 140,000 entities (rather than 40,000 before).

See below:

```
const remoteFile = bucket.file(file.name);

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: remoteFile.createReadStream()
});
console.log('file ready for processing');
lineReader.on('line', function (line) { ...
```

Comment: how are you creating the readline interface ?

Comment: added snippet of creating the linereader interface

Comment: How large is that file? What does ```prepare_entity``` do and return? What is ```datastore``` (is it something in-memory)? How do you know/suspect that ```readline``` runs out of memory? My bet would go on ```datastore.save``` instead. Side remark: note that the point of ```let``` is exactly that it is scoped on block level - pre-declaring entity, tripleKey and triple outside of the block defeats this detail and also makes the code longer.

Comment: The file is 1.2G. Datastore is the google cloud product. prepare_entity provide a dictionary with the tripleKey and three strings.

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Functions, [/tmp is a memory-based filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#local_disk).  That means your 1.2GB file living there is actually taking 1.2GB of memory.  That's a lot of memory.

If you need more memory, you can try to increase the memory limit for your functions in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions), up to 2GB max.

Instead, you might want to try to stream the file from its origin and process the stream instead of downloading the entire thing locally.  You'll save yourself money that way on memory used over time.

Comment: It has improved matters in that I am now getting to 140,000 records before the memory limit error (with 2GB).  The code is now as follows:

 
     `const remoteFile = bucket.file(file.name);
      const datastore = new Datastore({});
      let number_of_rows = 0;
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: remoteFile.createReadStream()
    });
    console.log('file ready for processing');
    lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
        let triple = parser.parse(line)[0];
        if (triple) { ...`

Comment: If you have updated code, add that to your question.  It's really difficult to read in a comment.